# How can I shuffle pages from a pdf file in a random order?

Tags: command-line, files, pdf, random

I would like to shuffle the pages of a pdf document in a random order.

How can this be done?

Comment: Oddly related: [Randomly reorder pages in PDF document](http://superuser.com/q/655718/354511); see also [Program needed for PDF Manipulation](http://superuser.com/q/58018/354511)  (both on Super User)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### With [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) and GNU coreutils

Determine the number of pages in the PDF file, then call [`shuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#shuf-invocation) to generate a randomized list of page numbers, and call `pdftk` again to extract the given sequence of pages.

```
pdftk original.pdf cat $(shuf 1-$(pdftk original.pdf dump_data | awk '$1=="NumberOfPages:" {print $2}')) output randomized.pdf
```

#### With Python and [PyPdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import random, sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input = PdfFileReader(sys.stdin)
output = PdfFileWriter()
pages = range(input.getNumPages())
random.shuffle(pages)
for i in pages:
     output.addPage(input.getPage(i))
output.write(sys.stdout)'
```

Usage: `/path/to/script <original.pdf >randomized.pdf`

Comment: Where did `pdftk` go? It's not in the Ubuntu repo anymore.

Comment: @OndraŽižka It got dropped from bionic due to library mishaps but should be back in cosmic since it's still in Debian. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029450/how-to-install-pdftk-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic for how to install it on bionic.

Answer (score 3):

We will use `pdftk` to perform operations on the pdf document.

1. Create a temporary working directory:

   ```
   mkdir tmp
   ```
2. Split the pdf document in many one page documents:

   ```
   pdftk original.pdf burst output tmp/pg_%02d.pdf
   ```
3. Rename the one-page document with random names:

   ```
   for name in tmp/*.pdf; do
      mv "tmp/$name" tmp/$(echo "$name" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ').pdf
   done
   ```
4. Merge all the one page documents:

   ```
   pdftk tmp/*.pdf cat output random.pdf
   ```
5. Clean the temporary working directory:

   ```
   rm -r tmp
   ```

Answer (score 3):

a little improvement to Gilles answer:

```
pdftk original.pdf cat $(shuf --input-range=1-$(pdftk original.pdf dump_data | awk '$1=="NumberOfPages:" {print $2}')) output randomized.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a version using pdfjoin/pdfjam (like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439960/10047)) by shuffling the sequence of page numbers and using that as input for pdfjoin:

```bash
# $1: source pdf file
# $2: last page number to consider
# $3: name of output file

for k in $(seq 1 $2 | shuf); do
    PAGES+=($1);
    PAGES+=($k);
done

pdfjoin ${PAGES[@]} --outfile $3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and probably doesnt come up too often but the answers here are out dated and the package has been changed slightly.
using python3 install the new package: `pip3 install PyPDF2`

This is my quick and dirty rewrite of the first answer but it works with the new package:

```
import random, sys
import PyPDF2 
#import PdfReader, PdfWriter
path = sys.argv[1]
out = sys.argv[2]
inp = PyPDF2.PdfReader(open(path, 'rb'))
output = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()




pages = len(inp.pages)
page_list = []
for i in range(pages):
     page_list.append(i)
random.shuffle(page_list)

for i in page_list:
     output.add_page(inp.pages[i])
output.write(out)
```

To use this script arg 1 is the source script and arg 2 is the output location:
`python3 shuffle.py normal.pdf randomized.pdf`