# How to reverse the page order of a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

Is there an easy (preferably command line) way to reverse the pages in a PDF file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can make use of `pdfjam` which provides a front end to the "pdfpages" LaTeX package (and thus comes for example with texlive).

It generally allows to create a new PDF file by selecting pages from multiple PDF files. Particularly it allows to specify decending ranges, using "last" to refer to the last page:

```
pdfjam myfile.pdf 'last-1' --outfile myfilereversed.pdf
```

reverses `myfile.pdf`.

For further possibilities see `pdfjam --help` and the [documentation of pdfpages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf).

Answer (score 35):

[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can also do this (it’s available in most distributions as `pdftk`):

```
pdftk myfile.pdf cat end-1 output myfilereversed.pdf
```

Comment: It's not available on Arch Linux (only via AUR) and there might be a good reason for that. Anyway, in that case, pdfjam is a good alternative.

Comment: @user905686 agreed, I’m presenting this as an alternative, not saying using `pdfjam` is wrong ;-).

Comment: It works on macOS too - in case anyone reaches this page from a Google search.

Answer (score 8):

You can use qpdf:

```
qpdf --empty --pages infile.pdf z-1 -- outfile.pdf
```

You can find more information [here](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.pdf) on page 11.

Comment: Of all the answers so far, this was the lightest, easiest install (`brew install qpdf`) on macOS 10.13.6.  Also it's very fast.

Answer (score 0):

1. From [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/jvenator/9672772a631c117da151):

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turforlag/homebrew-cervezas/master/pdftk.rb
```

2. In your `~/.bashrc`, put this:

```bsh
function pdfreverse {
  OUTPUT=/tmp/`/usr/bin/uuidgen`.pdf
  /usr/local/bin/pdftk "$1" cat end-1 output ${OUTPUT}
  /bin/rm "$1"
  /bin/mv ${OUTPUT} "$1"
}
```

Make a new Terminal window. Then run :

```
pdfreverse sample.pdf
```